# shield ui chart: generate series dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, shieldui

Is there a way to add series to a chart without knowing ahead of time how many series will be in it? For example I want to graph something on the X axis by month over a variable selection of years. Each year would be a series.

I thought about binding to IEnumerable while grouping by year--and creating a series on each group item, but I couldn't really envision the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work with a custom helper (HtmlHelper extension method). I adapted an example from http://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/aspnet-chart/programmatic-chart-creation, but that example is for ASP.NET web forms. I'm doing MVC. My solution involved using the ChartBuilder<> object within a helper.

```
public static class ChartExtensions
{
    public static ChartBuilder<PropertyPivotAverageAmountPerMonth_Result> AnnualComparison(this HtmlHelper html, int id)
    {
        MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities();
        var results = db.PropertyPivotAverageAmountPerMonth(id);
        ChartBuilder<PropertyPivotAverageAmountPerMonth_Result> chart = new ChartBuilder<PropertyPivotAverageAmountPerMonth_Result>(html, results);

        chart.AxisX(axisX => axisX.CategoricalValues("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"));
        chart.PrimaryHeader(header => header.Text("Annual Cost Comparisons"));


        foreach (var year in results)
        {
            chart.DataSeries(s => s.Line()
                .CollectionAlias(year.Year.ToString())
                .Data(new object[]
                    {
                        new { x=0, y=year.C1 },
                        new { x=1, y=year.C2 },
                        new { x=2, y=year.C3 },
                        new { x=3, y=year.C4 },
                        new { x=4, y=year.C5 },
                        new { x=5, y=year.C6 },
                        new { x=6, y=year.C7 },
                        new { x=7, y=year.C8 },
                        new { x=8, y=year.C9 },
                        new { x=9, y=year.C10 },
                        new { x=10, y=year.C11 },
                        new { x=11, y=year.C12 }
                    }));
        }
        return chart;
    }
```